# JS script is not loading in node.js

Tags: node.js

```
GET /contact 200 33ms - 2.26kb
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap.css 304 2ms
GET /stylesheets/header.css 304 1ms
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 2ms  
GET /stylesheets/contact.css 304 1ms
GET /javascripts/script.js 404 1ms
```

It keeps saying 404 when I try to load my javascript file. I have no idea why this is not working!

here are the lines that include the script:

```
extends layout
block css
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/contact.css')
  script(type="text/javascript", src='/javascripts/script.js')
```

the css is loading fine. here is the beginning of the script file:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  function() {
    console.log("inside basil script");
```

so it is definitely not working.

Why could this be happening? I know it is very simple but I can't figure it out. I just started using node.js

PS here is my app.js file (well part of it)

```
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: Where is your server side code, which serves static files from node?

Answer (score 2):

Do you use the http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html middleware in your application to serve directory with clien side javascripts? (i am 90% sure that you use expressJS framework).

Comment: yeah I am using expressJS. is that the problem?

Comment: place all css and client side javascripts in `public` directory
so it looks like this

```
    /public/
      /stylesheets/contact.css
      /javascripts/script.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the http codes you showed, I belive you only added one directory to serve static files and not added `javascripts` one.

so you have something like

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/stylesheets'));
```

now you need to add

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/javascripts'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

**use**

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

**It's work for me**